# doctrine2 get info about updated field

Tags: doctrine-orm, unit-of-work

HI, I want somehow to figure out which field was updated in the controller, I didn't found anything that might sound like what I'm trying to achieve in API doc for UnitOfWork. 
For example, I want to add on @PreUpdate code similar to this

```
/** @PreUpdate */ 
function updateAllIsDefaultFields(){
    //only if $this->isDefault propery for this entity is changed to 1 from its previous state, then update all other entities so they all have isDefault to 0

//else, means that this field is not changed, don't do anything

    }
```

Or this must be done from the controller on every action?

I know that I can do it every time just if $this->isDefault is set to 1, but I would like to avoid it for performance and I might find it useful for some other scenarios as well.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to write an [Event Subscriber](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/events.html#listening-to-lifecycle-events). Probably using an `onFlush` event, you can retrieve an Entities ChangeSet from the UnitOfWork to determine if a certain field has been updated and then do what ever you want.

Answer (score 1):

There are some good [behaviors](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions) for Doctrine2. Here is [example](http://www.gediminasm.org/article/timestampable-behavior-extension-for-doctrine-2#advanced-examples) of similar to your case.